# Odoo database migration from developers to prod without overwriting prod data

Tags: database, postgresql, odoo, migration, odoo-16

I have a question, I haven't been able to figure it out for more than two months. I am developing an application on Odoo in the Develop environment, after which I upload the updated Modules to the Production environment. But I can't do the same with the database without deleting the new user changes on the Product environment. + Odoo creates sessions and filestore.zip, and if some files are missing, then Odoo simply won't start.. Is there a solution to this? Or is there something I don't understand?

Attempts to directly change the base. Also, attempts to use ready-made applications, all this led to nothing, except for manual edits in the database, but not all dependencies are saved, and data is lost.

Comment: We aren't suppose to replace the database.
We should update the source code. Regarding 

the database itself, if the data needs any change, it requires a migration script to update the data.